# Transferring ownership of a case with live agent

Tags: liveagent, service-cloud-console, servicecloud

My questions is the following: I am implementing live agent, and when an agent accepts a chat a case will be created. During the chat if the agent transfers the chat to another agent, the case will follow (this is default behavior to my knowledge). I want the owner of the case to change to the agent who accepted the live agent transfer. Does anyone know if this is possible, and if so how I should go about implementing it?

Answer (score 0):

You could add use the methods available in the console toolkit to do this automatically when the case/chat are on the second agent 's screen or pop up a confirmation button upon to the agent upon which this action will be done.